# Sphinx 0.6.3: The languages module cannot be found

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I receive the following error message when I try to use the sphinx-quickstart generated make.bat command:

*make html*

> Error: The languages module cannot be found. Did you install Sphinx and its dependencies correctly?

I tried running the sphinx-build command and received the same error.

I am using Python 2.6.4 on Windows Vista. I have installed setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.6, and installed Sphinx 0.6.3 using easy_install.

It appears that **init**.py is failing when it tries to import cmdline (I grep'd part of the error message, and **init**.py was the only file that turned up) since the error shows up in the `try` block that imports cmdline.

```
try:
    from sphinx import cmdline
except ImportError, err:
    errstr = str(err)
    if errstr.lower().startswith('no module named'):
        whichmod = errstr[16:]
        hint = ''
        if whichmod.startswith('docutils'):
            whichmod = 'Docutils library'
        elif whichmod.startswith('jinja'):
            whichmod = 'Jinja library'
        elif whichmod == 'roman':
            whichmod = 'roman module (which is distributed with Docutils)'
            hint = ('This can happen if you upgraded docutils using\n'
                    'easy_install without uninstalling the old version'
                    'first.')
        else:
            whichmod += ' module'
        print >>sys.stderr, ('Error: The %s cannot be found. '
                             'Did you install Sphinx and its dependencies '
                             'correctly?' % whichmod)
        if hint:
            print >> sys.stderr, hint
        return 1
    raise
```

I do not see where "languages" would get passed as an argument, so I am confused at the error message.  I have searched for a solution, but have turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grepping through the sphinx package for "languages", the only relevant import is:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/sphinx/environment.py:from docutils.parsers.rst.languages import en as english
```

So most likely there's something wrong with your docutils installation. Admittedly, the error message would be more helpful if the full package path was reported.

Comment: I did not have docutils installed. For some reason, I believed that docutils was part of the setuptools package.  I too had grep'd for "languages" but I must have messed up the command because I didn't show any results.

Thanks for the help!